# How to run a XEN virtual machine ontop of a RHEL 7 installation and then run windows 7 pro 64-bit ontop of/in the XEN VM

Tags: windows-7, linux, 64-bit, virtualization, xen

I would like to run a XEN virtual machine ontop of an RHEL 7 installation and then run windows 7 pro 64-bit ontop of/in the XEN VM.

How best can I go about it.

Re: the baseline RHEL 7 is properly installed and running.

Thank you.

Comment: Are the RHEL 6 Tutorials good enough? http://wiki.xenproject.org/wiki/RHEL6_Xen4_Tutorial

Comment: Have you read this? https://wiki.centos.org/HowTos/Xen/Xen4QuickStart

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that this is possible, as well the Xen installer says this when you try to install the server software in a VM.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwEOL.jpg

What you could do though is run Xen as your host and then RHEL as your guest.

Update: Here is an image showing it working we have Xenserver 7 as our host (XS7-01) and we have two guests Windows 7 Pro x64 (CL-03) and RHEL 7 x64 (rhel7-01).
[image: XS7-Host, 2 Guests (W7Pro x64 and RHEL-7 x64]

Comment: Thanks Charles. How then can I incorporate Win 7 Pro as a second guest if it is possible. Thanks again.

Comment: I am bringing up a Xen Server right now, I will edit my answer as soon as I confirm it will work.

Comment: As far as adding it just put the iso on the server and your good.

Comment: @Juko If this was able to answer your question please mark it as an answer. Thanks.